# How to check if 1 id is less than another

Tags: php, mysql

How can I check to see if an item has a lower id than of another item on the same table?

I already have this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
if ($row[name] == $myusername) {
    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE name='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword'");
} }
```

But this is useless as it deletes the account as soon as it's made.

Comment: You need to give more information than that if you want an answer. What is the table you are looking at and what is the end result that you want?

Comment: `if ($id1 < $id2) { //do something }`. Not what you wanted? Provide a more clear question.

Comment: in the while statement, I want to compare the id's. so by saying (if this item's id is greater than the id of the same item ) do this. I'm just trying to get rid of duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add it in the WHERE clause

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE name='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword' AND users.id < [someOtheID]
```

You need to give a schema if you want a better answer

Comment: You have two `WHERE` clauses and you know the table is named `users`

Answer (score 0):

Just as you compare the name and password, also compare the id column.

```
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM users WHERE name='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword' AND id != $myid");
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you have the user you just added's id (that is an integer) in the variable $id

```
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM users 
    WHERE name='$myusername' AND password='$mypassword' AND id != $id"
);
```

That way you'll delete all users with the same username and password, that wasn't the row you just added.